# Is it possible to generate the DOM code from the HTML code?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to dynamically create element using DOM. I know how to do it using `document.createElement`, `appendChild` methods, but this is often a long process.

Suppose that I want to add this in my HTML page :

```
<div id="my_account" style="visibility:hidden">
  <input id="my_account_close" type="submit" value="Close" onclick="closeMyAccount();">
  <span id="my_account_username">Blabla</span>
  <input id="my_account_username_modify" type="submit" value="Change Name" onclick="modifyUserName();">
  <span id="my_account_email">a@asqs.com</span>
</div>
```

Do I have to create each element one by one and set all attributes, then use the `appendChild` methods ?
Is there a "magic" function that can take the html code which returns the parent element, so that I only have to add it at the end?

Comment: You can create a new `div`, set its `innerHTML` and then get a reference to the first child. That requires you to have the HTML as string in JS though, which can become quite messy if you use inline event handlers such as in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can just take that entire string and add it as innerHTML to a parent div.

It will be part of the dom on the very next line of code...

```
someParent.innerHTML = myHTMLString;
var d = document.getElementById('my_account');//this will return the first object in your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the innerHTML function:

```
document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML="<p>someHtml</p>";
```

Please notice JS does NOT support multiline strings.

Comment: You shouldn't `+=` to `innerHTML`

Comment: Yeah, because of event handlers etc.. but is the easiest way in this case.

Comment: More than just because of handlers. It doesn't make sense to serialize a DOM into a string, add a little to the string, parse the string into new nodes, and then destroy the old DOM and replace it with the new one. It's unnecessarily destructive.

Comment: Yes, I know about this, but I wanted to make the example as easy as possible.

Comment: I believe that you know it, but many others do not, and end up using this in very unfortunate circumstances like updating a large DOM in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a "magic" library called jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$("div").append("<div class='aaa'>Example</div>");
```